# How to increase the width for image in ViewPager2?

Tags: android

I'm using `viewPager2`  for image slides in my project and copied some code from [GitHub](https://github.com/askNilesh/carousel-layout-using-viewPager2) without proper knowledge and tried to understand but I'm unable to, can someone please tell me what's happening in my code and how to fix the image to screen width.

***activity_home.xml***

```
I have a toolbar on top od ScrollView and root layout as ConstaintLayout

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/viewpageimageSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

HomeScreen.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
    viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpageimageSlider);
    //hear i'm preparing list of images from drawable,
    sliderItemBeans = new ArrayList<>();
    sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.plateofcarrot));
    sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.bread));
    sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.cucumber));
    sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.vegetables));
    sliderItemBeans.add(new SliderItemBean(R.drawable.donuts));
    viewPager2.setAdapter(new SliderAdapter(sliderItemBeans, viewPager2));

    viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(RecyclerView.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);

    float pageMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.pageMargin);//10
    float pageOffset = getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.offset);//20

//I don't understand the code in here what's actually happening.

    viewPager2.setPageTransformer((page, position) -> {
        float myOffset = position * -(2 * pageOffset + pageMargin);
        if (position < -1) {
            page.setTranslationX(-myOffset);
        } else if (position <= 1) {
            float scaleFactor = Math.max(0.7f, 1 - Math.abs(position - 0.14285715f));
            page.setTranslationX(myOffset);
            page.setScaleY(scaleFactor);
            page.setAlpha(scaleFactor);
        } else {
            page.setAlpha(0);
            page.setTranslationX(myOffset);
        }
    });
    viewPager2.setPageTransformer(compositePageTransformer);
    viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            sliderHandler.removeCallbacks(sliderRunnable);
            sliderHandler.postDelayed(sliderRunnable, 3000);//slide duration
        }
    });
}

private Runnable sliderRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        viewPager2.setCurrentItem(viewPager2.getCurrentItem() + 1,true);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sliderHandler.removeCallbacks(sliderRunnable);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sliderHandler.postDelayed(sliderRunnable, 3000);
}
```

Adapter.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slideImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ImageView>
```